# Sorting a listview (Win32/C++)

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I'm trying to sort a listview when the user clicks on the column header.

I am catching the LVN_COLUMNCLICK notification like so:

```
  case LVN_COLUMNCLICK:
  {
     NMLISTVIEW*    pListView   = (NMLISTVIEW*)lParam;
     BOOL test = ListView_SortItems ( m_hDuplicateObjectsList, ListViewCompareProc, pListView->iSubItem );
     break;
  }
```

However it seems to fail. My test variable is FALSE and my ListViewCompareProc never gets hit (it has a simple return 1 while I am trying to hit a debug point inside of it).

Is there something I am missing for sorting a listview?

Comment: what is the type m_hDuplicateObjectsList?

Comment: m_hDuplicateObjectList is an HWND that I received by calling GetDlgItem ( hWindow IDC_DUPLICATEOBJECTS ). It is valid, as I can call other ListView_ methods on it.

Comment: Qualifying "C++" with "Unmanaged" makes me a sad panda. :'( (I'd've used "Win32" for the tag/title instead)

Comment: Any result from `GetLastError`?

Comment: Typical for common controls, but worth checking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the `LVS_OWNERDATA` style on your control?

There are a number of features incompatible with that style, including sorting:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774735%28VS.85%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774735%28VS.85%29.aspx#Compatibility_issues)

Comment: Thanks. Was struggling with it for sometime. Should have tried SO first.

Comment: From you MSDN link: `However, some messages have limitations or are unsupported when you use the LVS_OWNERDATA style.` [...] `LVM_SORTITEMS Is not supported. It is the application's responsibility to present the items in the desired order.`